# How to mininize expression using boolean algebra?

Tags: digital, circuit

Here is expression that we have to minimize with boolean algebra:

y = /A/B/C/D + /A/B/CD + /AB/CD + A/B/C/D + A/B/CD + A/BC/D + A/BCD.

I know little bit about that, please help!!!

The answer is /A/CD + /B/C + A/B

Answer (score 0):

You need to put those [minterms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minterm) on a [Karnaugh Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map) and find the minimized form after grouping.

Comment: There's an online Karnaugh Map tool [here](http://www.ee.calpoly.edu/media/uploads/resources/KarnaughExplorer_1.html).